# Difference between Concatenation and Append

Tags: bash, paste, cat

What is the basic and essential difference between Concatenate and Append

Comment: What is the context here? Did you read about these somewhere? They are usually used in this fashion: "Concatenate 'a' *and* 'b' to get 'ab'", "Append 'b' *to* 'a' to get 'ab'".

Comment: Should this be asked on http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do the `paste` and `cat` tags carry any contextual meaning that we should be aware of?

Comment: This question should not have been closed; its a valid comp-sci question with a complex set of answers. For example, in type-theory, there is a dependency on the types of the two parts (you can concatenate anything, but you can only append things of the same type) For tensor classes, concatenation is the direct product or tensor product, while append is the direct sum. This deserves a detailed explication by someone who knows this stuff.

Comment: I agree, it is weird that this question was closed and the answers are so brief

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Concatenate" joins two specific items together, whereas "append" adds what you specify to whatever may already be there.

Comment: Can you please explain the same concept with any example..?

Comment: `echo "$foo$bar"` `echo "$baz" > 42.txt ; echo "$quux" >> 42.txt`

Comment: concatenate is actually sequencing one after other(column wise). Append is sequencing one after other(row wise)

Comment: The concatentation of two types A and B results in the pair-type AB. By contrast, you cannot (normally/usually) append type A to type B unless A and B are the same type. The result of the append is another object of type A.

For things like strings or lists, both A and B are the same type, and its conventional to confuse (intentionally, e.g. duck-type) a pair of strings as a single string or a pair of lists as a single list. With this rule, concatenation and append become the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

When use `Concat` or `append` on two strings they both may give you same result when you output them 
but the
 main difference is on using concatenation new string object is created where as its not the same in case of `StrinBuffer APPEND()`